# What is the secret to getting tag helpers to work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to implement this sample and for the life of me cannot get it to work:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.2#condition-tag-helper

What am I doing wrong

I have copied the code almost directly from the sample, only changing the namespace...

ConditionTagHelper.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace My.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = nameof(Condition))]
    public class ConditionTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public bool Condition { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if (!Condition)
                output.SuppressOutput();
        }
    }
}
```

_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using  My.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper My.TagHelpers.ConditionTagHelper, My.TagHelpers
```

_Layout.cshtml is used, and is standard from the asp.net core MVC project
Home Controller just returns a View and the view contains only this.
Index.cshtml

```
<div condition="@true">Shown</div>
<div condition="@false">Hidden</div>
```

I expected only the word "Shown" to be on the screen, however both words appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `_ViewImports.cshtml` file is incorrect. You are not actually importing the taghelper into your project so it is not being evaluated. The parameters to `@addTagHelper` are

- The full name of the TagHelper to add (including the namespace) or * for all
- The name of the Assembly the TagHelper is in

So, assuming your assembly is called `My`, you need to change your line to

```
@addTagHelper My.TagHelpers.ConditionTagHelper, My
```

More information can be found in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2#managing-tag-helper-scope)

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it.  I did not understand the relationship between the first and second parts of the @addTagHelper.